# Number formatting: how to convert 1 to "01", 2 to "02", etc.?

Tags: c#

I have numbers like 1, 2, and 3, and I would like to make them into strings, "01", "02" and "03". How can I do this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=Number%20formatting

Answer (score 128, accepted):

[Here is the MSDN article on formatting numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). To pad to 2 digits, you can use:

```
n.ToString("D2")
```

Comment: dotnet 6 allows `$"{n:D2}"` syntax.

Answer (score 34):

```
string.Format("{0:00}", yourInt);

yourInt.ToString("00");
```

Both produce 01, 02, etc...

Answer (score 12):

```
string.Format("{0:00}",1); //Prints 01
string.Format("{0:00}",2); //Prints 02
```

Answer (score 8):

With new C# (I mean version 6.0), you can achieve the same thing by just using **String Interpolation**

```
int n = 1;
Console.WriteLine($"{n:D2}");
```

Answer (score 0):

as an example

```
int num=1;
string number=num.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')
```

just simple and Worked.