# Display Float as String with at Least 1 Decimal Place

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

I want to display a float as a string while making sure to display at least one decimal place. If there are more decimals I would like those displayed.

For example:
1 should be displayed as 1.0
1.2345 should display as 1.2345

Can someone help me with the format string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972949/number-formatting)

Comment: Its not a duplicate, my question is how to display a min of 1 decimal and no maximum # of decimals.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use ToString(".0###########") with as much # as decimals you want.

Comment: Per the [IEEE 754 Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008), with `float` you can use 6 `#`s after the `.0` as you get ~7 decimal digits of precision. For `double` you can use 15 `#`s as you get ~16 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: @Six: thanks for the information. I will use it for myself too!

Comment: @User7116 This is misleading. For values really close to 0 the approximate range of a single is ±1.5 x 10−45 which is far more than 7 digit. You should check your precision based on your current value [IEEE_754 Precisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats).

Answer (score 14):

This solution is similar to what other are saying, but I prefer to use string.Format.
For example:

```
float myFloat1 = 1.4646573654;
float myFloat2 = 5;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number 1 : {0:0.00##}", myFloat1));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Number 2 : {0:0.00##}", myFloat2));

// Newer Syntax
Console.WriteLine($"{myFloat1:0.00##}";
Console.WriteLine($"{myFloat2:0.00##}";
```

This would produce :

```
Number 1 : 1.4646
Number 2 : 5.00
Number 1 : 1.4646
Number 2 : 5.00
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
doubleNumber.ToString("0.0###");
```

And, for your reference (double ToString method): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx

Comment: That forces everything to have 1 decimal place. So in this case 1.2345 would display as 1.2

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to do a min of 1 decimal and no max

Comment: No it doesn't: `(1.23456789).ToString("0.0#######") = "1.23456789"`

Comment: @KrisTrip: How many decimals are you expecting? Only a finite amount can be represented on a standard computer. (And how many are actually going to be useful to the viewer?)

Comment: @Deanna - Originally the formatting was "0.0" which did force 1 decimal. It was edited after that comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
float fNumber = 1.2345; // Your number
string sNumber = fNumber.ToString(); // Convert it to a string
If ((sNumber.Contains(".") == false) && (sNumber.Contains(",") == false)) // Check if it's got a point or a comma in it...
{
    sNumber += ".0"; // ... and if not, it's an integer, so we'll add it ourselves.
}
```

Comment: That breaks internationalization (works great for en-US, but not for others)

Comment: this might not work depending on localisation settings. (if thats a concern)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought of the fact that it wouldn't work on my own computer because of the localisation :p Fixed the if clause though. Problem is that it's a bit dodgy to get it to detect wheter it should add a point or a comma.

Comment: What you're really looking for @RobinJ is the [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx). However, this is still a brittle choice.