# Show 2 decimals places (unless there are more significant digits)

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, significant-digits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display Float as String with at Least 1 Decimal Place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038994/display-float-as-string-with-at-least-1-decimal-place)

Given the following values:

- 23.50
- 15
- 19.3500
- 31.505
- 45.6670

How can I achieve the following display:

- 23.50
- 15.00
- 19.35
- 31.505
- 45.667

What I am trying to do is force 2 decimal places UNLESS there are more "significant" digits, in which case I'd like to show them as well.

Note:  The value is currently stored as a `Decimal?`

Comment: One of these answers may work for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038994/display-float-as-string-with-at-least-1-decimal-place

Comment: hope this helps you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

Comment: Might want to change the question to say "non-zero" digits since the term "significant digits" has a very specific meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
yourNumber.ToString(".00######")
```