# I want to display the answer upto four decimal places after round off

Tags: c#

I want to display the answer up to four decimal places after round off. I have tried many functions but all are giving same answer up to 1 decimal place i.e., "0.9". I want to display "0.9000".

Here is my code:

```
float x2 = 0; 
decimal l = 0;
l =Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round( (9 / 10.0) +(x2 / 10.0),4));
Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Comment: try `Console.WriteLine("{0:F4}", l);`

Comment: Try using google or stack overflow search before wasting peoples time. For example, you can search on "C# format decimal with 4 decimal places" or "c# format number 4 decimal places". Both give valid answers within the first few results. Learning to use Google and other internet searches is key to becoming a successful software engineer. Nobody can know or remember everything.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this Post

[Display Float as String with at Least 1 Decimal Place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038994/display-float-as-string-with-at-least-1-decimal-place)

This should answer your question

Comment: Link-only answers are not good, since links tend to die. Provide context for the link in your answer, please.